Creating an interactive checkbox in Google Colab to control debug output during model training
I'm trying to create an interactive checkbox in Google Colab that allows me to toggle debug output on and off during the training of a neural network. Specifically, I want to:

Display a checkbox in the notebook.
Print debug information when the checkbox is checked.
Stop printing when the checkbox is unchecked.
Be able to toggle this checkbox while a loop (simulating the training process) is running.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm attempting:
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets

@interact(check=widgets.Checkbox(value=True, description='Print debug info'))
def on_change(check):
    if check:
        print("Debug info is now being printed")
    else:
        print("Debug info is not being printed")

# Simulating the training loop
while True:
    if on_change.widget.children[0].value:
        print("Debug information")
    else:
        break


The problem is that while this code displays the checkbox, changing its value doesn't affect the loop - it's not responsive. The loop continues to run regardless of the checkbox state.
How can I modify this code to create an interactive checkbox that can control the debug output in real-time during a running loop? Is there a better approach to achieve this in Google Colab?

See here. It doesn't use a checkbox, but the issues are similar. Also see the discussion and links in the comment below furas' answer.
